# Command line tool for interacting with Bluetooth Low Energy devices, similar to gatttool

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bluetooth, python

I've just found out that some Python code I've got working on Linux also needs to work on OSX.

For reliability reasons, on Linux I've been using a cludgy but effective approach to reading and writing characteristics on Bluetooth Low Energy devices. I've been simply spawning a subprocess that calls the `gatttool` command with the appropriate arguments and capturing the output. (None of the libraries that I tried would work reliably).

So now that I have to get it working on OSX, it would be wonderful to just use the same approach, but with a tool that works on OSX. Requirements for the tool are:

- Read from an arbitrary bluetooth characteristic on an arbitrary device
- Write to an arbitrary bluetooth characteristic on an arbitrary device

Is there such a tool for OSX? If not is there a way I can get `gatttool` working under OSX?

Thanks

Comment: I'm about to tackle the same problem, do you mind sharing how you got on with the posted solution?

Answer (score 1):

GATT isn't exposed on macOS as easily as [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH1-SW1) (which you can get to easily from the command line with swift or python and objective c bridging).

- https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BluefruitLE/tree/master/Adafruit_BluefruitLE/corebluetooth
- https://github.com/karulis/pybluez

The pybluez code is very well commented and has good nuggets like:

> See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iobluetooth
>   for Apple's IOBluetooth documentation.
>
> See http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net for details on how to access Objective-C
>   classes through PyObjC.

If those python examples don't work, then if you are a developer, I would start with the Additional Tools downloads for Xcode (latest [beta version](http://adcdownload.apple.com/WWDC_2017/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_9_beta/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_9_beta.dmg)). If you're not a developer, then the free Xcode would be where I start to see how quickly you could get to GATT or see if the CoreBluetooth API are suitable for what you want to do.